# Implicit comparison with ほど

Tags: grammar, comparative-constructions, comparison

Does Japanese have a way to do an implicit comparison using ほど or より? For instance,

> Since they are cold, these cookies aren't as good.

Here, we don't specify as good as what?  usual? other cookies? when they are warm?

> 冷たいのでクッキーのほうが良くない

Comment: I see two words for "comparison" here. Good and also **cold**. Unless you're talking about absolute zero, it's a relative thing, so this also begs the question "cold compared to what?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make an implicit comparison, you can use それほど, literally "to that extent":

> [冷]{つめ}たいから・[冷]{さ}めているから、それほど[美味]{おい}しくない
>
> "Since they are cold, they aren't delicious to that extent"

If you want to reference something specific, maybe yesterday's cookies, you can say:

> [昨日]{きのう}ほど[美味]{おい}しくない
>
> "They aren't as delicious as yesterday"

Or even:

> 昨日[思]{おも}ったほど、美味しくない
>
> "They aren't as delicious as I remember"

Answer (score 2):

There's the それほど construct for implicit comparisons.

> 冷めているので**それほど**美味しくない