# ～ほど～ない vs ～より～ない

Tags: grammar, nuances, comparative-constructions

In reading [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/93189/implicit-comparison-with-%e3%81%bb%e3%81%a9/93195?noredirect=1#93195), it's occurred to me that I don't know the difference between the following constructions:

> 自転車に乗るのは思ったより易しくない
> 自転車に乗るのは思ったほど易しくない

Is the difference really just as the literal translation suggests? That より is "not as easy" and ほど is "not easy to the extent" (but potentially still easy)?

Comment: Here's a relevant Japanese article you should read: [比較の「より」と「ほど」の違い](https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7504)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`～より～ない` is just comparing two things and showing their relationship. We can't tell to what extent they are. `自転車に乗るのは思ったより易しくない`: The speaker tried to ride a bike, and it was simply more difficult than they expected. Not sure if they could or not.

`～ほど～ない` is also comparing two but also implying its extent. `自転車に乗るのは思ったほど易しくない`: The speaker could have ridden a bike, though that was a bit more tricky than they thought.

Usually, `～より～` is used with a positive form of a word, so this time `思ったより難しい` is more natural. `～ほど～` can only be used with a negative form.

Comment: To clarify, AほどBない always means that B is true, but not to the extent of A?

Comment: Yes. For example, `冬は夏ほど暑くない` sounds strange.